# Specify exact address in assembler source

Tags: gcc, assembly, pci, rom

So I am trying to add a [PCI data structure](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~harris/ics216/pci/PCI_22.pdf) table to a [ROM image](https://github.com/hildred/sgabiosm) and I need to place a pointer at offset 18h. I suppose I could pad from the start, but I don't think that would be a general solution. How do you tell the assembler or linker to put code or data at a specific place other than offset 0?

Comment: Typically you would write a [linker script](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Scripts.html) which lays out the parts of the program into specific segments tailored to the needs of your application. However to small binary images not fully utilizing the linker (so called absolute assembly code) you may try [the .org directive](http://web.mit.edu/gnu/doc/html/as_toc.html#SEC106).

Comment: You can put it into a separate section then use `--section-start` option to `ld`.